# Is it prohibited to share consumable IAP's between two apps?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

We are developing two apps that use the same server(this apps are different but shares user in-game money balance). User has an account on the server and server has information how-much in-game money was purchased by user using consumable IAP's. Can we share this in-app balance between two apps? It seems to be prohibited by 11.2 of App Store Review Guidelines:

> Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to
>   purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be
>   rejected

But maybe it is only about restoring non-consumable in-app purchases? Can I use mechanism based on our own server to share in-app balance between two apps?

Comment: It's probably fine, but you can contact Apple through ADC to ask. Also, this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow because it's not about computer programming.

Comment: Imagine a consumable purchase where I get 100 coins for one dollar, and in app A a coin gives me an hour of gameplay, but in app B I only get a minute of gameplay. Customers who paid to get a lot of playtime in A and lose their coins quickly when using B would be mightily annoyed.

Answer (score 0):

There should not be a problem with 11.2 because the product was purchased using IAP.  However you have a significant 'trust me' issue with Apple since Apple has no way of assuring that your server is not charging outside of the App.

You can use MKSession (bluetooth) or iCloud to accomplish the same transfer function.